# Most efficient way to convert datetime string (Jul 25, 2016 11:51:32 PM) into another string (YYYYMMDD) in python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

I have a string representing a datetime such as : 
"Jul 19, 2016 4:45:57 PM"

I would like to convert this to the following string:  "20160725"

What is the most efficient way to do this in python?

Thanks :)

Note : I need to do this in order to input this date into a csv file later on, which will be used to show a line chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) methods of the `datetime` module. The following does what you want:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

s = "July 25, 2016 - 11:51:32 PM"
old_format = '%B %d, %Y - %H:%M:%S %p'
new_format = '%Y%m%d'
r = dt.strptime(s, old_format).strftime(new_format)
print(r)
# '20160725'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, this returns the following : 
ValueError: time data 'Jul 19, 2016 4:45:57 PM' does not match format '%B %d, %Y - %H:%M:%S'

Comment: But you realise there is an extra `'PM'` which is different from what you originally posted?

Comment: Oh thanks for the remark ! I did not notice the pm :) that is true

Comment: I've updated my answer. Adding a `%p` in the format fixes that. And that hyphen, do you have it in your original data?

Comment: for those who google this, if you are dealing with a complete month (ex: July) use %B, and if you are dealing with abbreviation (ex: Jul) use %b. 

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm